# Accessing TypeScript Optional Object Properties With a String

Tags: typescript, types, typing, strong-typing, conditional-types

I'm working in an existing JavaScript codebase. There is a class which exposes pre-defined functions (e.g. "copy", "paste") for utility. The class can be instantiated with "extension" functions, which allow users to register other utility functions for later use.

This code isn't typed, so I'm trying to add types to the signatures. But I'm having a lot of trouble with the function that gets a utility function by name (`get(name)`). A minimised version of the code (with my attempt at adding types) is as follows:

```ts
class Operation {
    private extensions: {[key: string]: () => void}
    constructor(extensions: {[key: string]: () => void}) {
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }
    get(name: string): () => void {
        if (this[name]) {
            return this[name].bind(this)
        }
        if (this.extensions[name]) {
            return this.extensions[name].bind(this)
        }
        // default to copy
        return this.copy.bind(this);
    }
    copy() {
        console.log('copied');
    }
    paste() {
        console.log('pasted');
    }
}
const operation = new Operation({'cut': () => { console.log('cut'); }});
operation.get('cut')();
```

This fails because of `this[name]`: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Operation' has no index signature ts(7053)".

Since this function is meant to accept arbitrary strings (because of the overrides), I don't think I can avoid typing the function as `get(name: string)`. I couldn't figure out from the TypeScript documentation how to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), e.g. `get(name: string | keyof Operation)`, and I'm not convinced that's the right solution.

What is the best way to (re-)structure and type the `get(name)` function with strict types, given that `name` is not guaranteed to be a property of `Operation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check (in JavaScript, not TypeScript) that the key being accessed is one of the ones directly on the class that you want to permit - eg `copy` or `paste`. Then, TS will automatically infer that such access is allowed.

```
get(name: string): () => void {
    if (name === 'copy' || name === 'paste') {
        return this[name].bind(this)
    }
    if (this.extensions[name]) {
        return this.extensions[name].bind(this)
    }
    // default to copy
    return this.copy.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: This is great!  But is there any way to do this so that the names do not have to be hard-coded in the function?  i.e. if someone adds a new pre-defined function, they won't have to modify the contents of `get()`?

Comment: Technically, you can bypass anything with a type assertion, but I prefer to avoid those because they're less type-safe. I'd prefer to list out the properties individually. But you can do `if (Operation.prototype.hasOwnProperty(name)) { return this[name as Exclude<keyof Operation, 'get'>].bind(this) }` TypeScript doesn't work as elegantly as would be ideal with these sorts of overloaded functions with dynamic keys.